# Crystal Report with Error : A number range is required here

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using the crystal report, in that i am using code like below to show the SQL data into the crystal report,

```
string req = "{View_EODPumpTest.ROId} IN " + str + " AND " + "({View_EODPumpTest.RecordCreatedDate}>=date(" + fromDate.Year + " , " + fromDate.Month + " , " + fromDate.Day + ")" + "AND" + "{View_EODPumpTest.RecordCreatedDate}<=date(" + toDate.Year + " , " + toDate.Month + " ," + toDate.Day + " ))";

ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
rep.Load(Server.MapPath("PumpTestReport.rpt"));

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["fDate"].ToString());
                DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["tDate"].ToString());
                CrystalReportViewer_PumpTest.ReportSource = rep;
                //CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = str;
                rep.RecordSelectionFormula = str;
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject from = ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)rep.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtFrom"]);
                from.Text = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject to = ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)rep.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtTO"]);
                to.Text = toDate.ToShortDateString();
                //Session["Repo"] = rep;
                CrystalReportViewer_PumpTest.RefreshReport();
```

after running my application it executes fine with no exception but such error i am getting,

```
A number range is required here. Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\Delmon\LOCALS~1\Temp\PumpTestReport {14E557A7-51B3-4791-9C78-B6FBAFFBD87C}.rpt: Error in formula . '{View_EODPumpTest.ROId} IN ['15739410','13465410'] AND ({View_EODPumpTest.RecordCreatedDate}>=date(2010 , 12 , 1)AND{View_EODPumpTest.RecordCreatedDate}<=date(2010 , 12 ,25 ))' A number range is required here.
```

error.

what i will do for this?

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not included the definition of 'str' in your code sample, but I'd guess that it's a comma-separated set of values. For Crystal to interpret this you have to put the value range inside [ and ], not the standard ( and ) you might use in SQL. Eg,

```
{View_EODPumpTest.ROId} IN [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: if you're using as a parameter enclose it in brackets:  [{?parm}]